# Cannot import images from a sibling directory - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have tried many ways to get out of this problem.
I have a folder named `Screens` in which I have a file name `HomeScreen.js`

```
assets--
       |__ padlock.png
Screens--
        |__ HomeScreen.js
```

When I am trying to import `padlock.png` into `HomeScreen.js` it gives following error.

> Unable to resolve module ./assets/padlock.png from D:\User\react\myproject\Screens\HomeScreen.js:

Following methods I have tried in `HomeScreen.js`

```
const imageLock = require("../assets/padlock.png"); //Not working
const imageLock = { uri: "../assets/padlock.png" }; //Not Working
import imageLock from "../assets/padlock.png"; //not working
```

I have make sure that `padlock.png` exist and I am not making any mistakes. Full error message is as below.

> Unable to resolve module ./assets/padlock.png from D:\User\react\myproject\Screens\HomeScreen.js:

> None of these files exist:
>
> - padlock.png
> - Screens\assets\padlock.png\index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
>   27 | const imageLock = require("../assets/padlock.png");
>   |                             ^
>   28 |
>   29 | export default function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
>   30 |   const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);

[image: This is directory structure]

Comment: From the path description the directory is called `Assets` not `assets` - maybe just a typo?

Comment: My Bad, updated the question. it actually `assets`

Comment: There is another typo sssets

Answer (score -1):

Did you try

```
    <Image
      style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
      source={require('../assets/padlock.png')}
    />
```